# How to filter MQ SQL query results

Tags: sql-server

This query:

```
select (sum(pages_kb))/1024 as 'sizein_mb',type as 'clerktype'
from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
group by type order by (sum(pages_kb)*128)/1024 desc
```

Returns:

```
  sizein_mb   clerktype  
1 10588       MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL
2 6093        MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIONS
3 458         MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE
4 107         CACHESTORE_SQLCP
```

I just need "10588"

I've tried using a select-where at the end:

```
select (sizein_mb) where clerktype = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL'
```

but this just returns an invalid column name error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'clerktype'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'sizein_mb'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Clerktype is an alias that you assignate to "type", so you need to replace clerktype by Type. Also sizein_mb...

```
select (sum(pages_kb))/1024
from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
where type = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a subquery out of your original query, and select outside of that. Like so:

```
SELECT sizein_mb
FROM
(
    SELECT (SUM(pages_kb))/1024 AS 'sizein_mb',type AS 'clerktype'
    FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
    GROUP BY type
)
WHERE clerktype = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL'
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0):

alias names cannot be used in where clause.

The solution would be to replace `where clerktype = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL'`
with `having type = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL'`

Comment: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3`
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.`
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6`
`Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Answer (score 0):

Add `HAVING` should filter the aggregate you want.

```
SELECT (SUM(pages_kb))/1024 AS 'sizein_mb', type AS 'clerktype'
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
GROUP BY type 
HAVING (SUM(pages_kb))/1024 = 10588
ORDER BY sizein_mb DESC
```